# fatal error: procinfo.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, cygwin

I am attempting to compile C program on Window platform (currently, it's running on AIX).
   Problem is: when I build this program, the compiler could not find procinfo.h file.
   I spent much time to search on the internet but still cannot solve this problem.

```
fatal error: procinfo.h: No such file or directory
```

I am wonderful to receive your support. All helps will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you compile it?

Comment: Details, please - compiler, version, Windows version, etc.

Comment: @Radoslav Hristov: I'm using Cygwin to compile it on Window 2k3 R2. In addition, IDE is Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, procinfo.h is a part of unix kernel headers, it is not available on Windows, at least not in a native Windows development environment (like MSVC). Your specific C program can be written in a way that is not compatible with Windows or might require a significant effort for porting.

Comment: At the first time, there were many problem but I could solve them already. This may the last one that I'm facing, I think.
Could you please give me more detail? thanks!

Comment: @NghiaVu: Try to isolate where an how the declarations from `procinfo.h` are used in the code and try to exclude this functionallty from the code. If this is not possible you most likley need to recode such functionallity for the windows platform using what windows provides as substitute.

Comment: @alk : This may difficult because I just receive code from the other team (I totally don't know about C). Btw, thanks for your suggestion. Your idea should help me so far.